Composition of functions, once for all
I need certainties. Consider two functions $f: A \to B$ and $g: C \to D$. For what I am going to ask, it's not a loss of generality if we consider multivariable functions with domains and or codomains as subsets (proper or not) of $\mathbb{R}^n$. In any case let's remain vague.
Now my "problem" is to fully understand, once for all, the conditions for which the composition $f\circ g$ (or equivalently, with the obvious variations, $g\circ f$) do exist.
What I understood so far while studying
Given the functions above, let's say we want to compute $f\circ g$.
Well in order for this to exist I understood that we have to have $g(C) \subseteq A$, and since we always have $g(C) \subseteq D$ we hence say equivalently $D \subseteq A$.
The details I am missing
Assuming it's ok so far, here is what I am missing:

Is it necessary or sufficient to have $g(C) \subseteq A$?

Is in general (and, if yes, why) $D \subseteq A$ actually a strict equality, that is $D = A$?


I'm asking these questions because after having read some answers over here I am a bit confused.
Domain and Codomain
After this, reading the wikipedia page made me even more confused because I thought that then the composition $f\circ g$ would be $f\circ g: g(C) \to A$ where instead by reading the article I interpreted it is $f\circ g: C \to B$.
My head is hurting.
Of course once understood this I will be able to paraphrase all this to $g\circ f$.
Thank you so much.

"and since we always have $g(C) \subseteq D$ we hence say equivalently $D \subseteq A$" This is not equivalent at all: If $g(C) = {1}$, $D$ could be ${1}$, ${1, 2, 3}$, $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{R}$, etc., so $g(C) \subseteq A$ is potentially a much weaker condition.

@BenSteffan You're right, I wrote a wrong thing there

Let's address your immediate questions:

Is it necessary or sufficient to have $g(C) \subseteq A$? It is both necessary and sufficient. Why necessary? If there is some $c \in C$ such that $g(c) \notin A$, then you cannot make sense of $(f \circ g)(c) = f(g(c))$: After all, $f$ is only defined for elements of $A$. Why sufficient? It's almost the same argument: All that's required for $f \circ g$ to be well-defined is that $g(c) \in A$ for all $c \in C$, so that you can apply $f$ to it.
Is in general (and if yes, why) $D \subseteq A$ actually a strict equality, that is $D = A$? No. As I noted in the comments, for a start $D \subseteq A$ need not hold to begin with; it is not true that $g(C) \subseteq D$ is equivalent to $D \subseteq A$ as you claimed. For instance, let $g\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be the function defined by $g(n) = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f\colon \{1, 2, 3\} \to \mathbb{N}$ be the function given by $f(1) = 17$, $f(2) = 0$, and $f(3) = 29891$. Obviously $\mathbb{N} \not \subseteq \{1, 2, 3\}$, yet the composition $f \circ g$ is well-defined: After all $g(\mathbb{N}) = \{1\} \subset \{1, 2, 3\}$.

Next, let's talk about your confusion about domain and codomain: If $f\colon A \to B$ and $g\colon C \to D$ are functions such that $f \circ g$ is defined, then $f \circ g$ has domain $C$ and codomain $B$: This is easiest remembered when you write $f \circ g$ as
$$
    C \overset{g}{\to} g(C) \overset{f}{\to} B
$$
(and remember the reading "$f \circ g$ is $f$ after $g$").

A final note on usage: In practice you'll find that people will mostly avoid composing functions when $A \neq C$ since this always poses the question of well-definedness. If you have $f$ and $g$ as above with $A \neq C$, we generally say first that $f$ has image contained in $C$ (in the case that $C \subset A$) or otherwise justify why we can understand $f$ as map $f\colon A \to C$.

Thank you so much! I will study this carefully now!
